# How can I track the items in ngRepeat (AngularJS)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tracking

Hej folks,

I've a simple problem, but I cannot find a solution.
I have a search input-field and you can search in the table in all columns. But I want to track the items in ngRepeat but it doesn't work for yet.

Here's the Input field for searching items:

```
<div>
  <input type="search" ng-model="searchText" />
</div>
```

Table with ngRepeat:

```
...
<tr ng-repeat="item in filtered = (persons | filter:searchText track by item.name)">
   <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
   <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
</tr>
...
```

Can anyone help me? :)

Comment: What do you mean by "i want to track" ?

Comment: what do you mean by track items?

Comment: What do you mean by tracking? Are you sure you're looking for the functionality provided by [track by](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)?

Comment: _it doesn't work_ what you mean? seems you have wrong syntax in `ngRepeat`

Comment: Have you tried `item in filtered = (persons | filter:searchText) track by item.name`?

Comment: I think the easiest way is to make a new person array filtered by searchText

Comment: for example you have 3 columns. ID, name and age. ID and age have the type number. So when I want to search the age and type in the input field "30" then I want only the result for age. When a person have die id=30 but isn't 30 years old, then the person isn't in the result you know?

Comment: Hej Thomas.. yes I tried your example but it is the same problem :)

Comment: "If you do need to repeat duplicate items, you can substitute the default tracking behavior with your own using the track by expression" I don't think you want to work with duplicates here, see Grundy solution I think it will be fine without 'track by'

Comment: @yuro, as for [_track by_](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#Tracking%20and%20Duplicates): _If you do need to repeat duplicate items, you can substitute the default tracking behavior with your own using the_ *track by* _expression._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understand you not need *track by*, and just [*filter*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) enough

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in persons | filter:{ name: searchText} ">
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.persons = [{
      name: 'a',
      id: 1
    }, {
      name: 'aa',
      id: 2
    }, {
      name: 'aaaa',
      id: 3
    }, {
      name: 'aaaaa',
      id: 4
    }, {
      name: 'aaaaaa',
      id: 5
    }, {
      name: 'aaaaaaa',
      id: 6
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div>
    <input type="search" ng-model="searchText" />
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in persons | filter:{name:searchText}">
      <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: But I want to search only IDs for example, then I need to use "track by..."

Comment: so you can use _id_ as filter parameter, you not need _track by_ in your case methinks, in my snippet filtered only by _name_ if you change _name_ to _id_ if would be filter only by _id_, without any _track by_

Comment: You mean using 'searchText' to filter only on IDs ?

Comment: @bviale you ask me, or OP? :-)

Comment: @Grundy It was for OP, was trying to understand what he was really looking for ^^

Comment: @bviale yep, look alike OP a bit confused with filter and _track by_ :-)

Comment: Sorry Grundy your solution was the right! :D I've not used the "name: ...".. Now it works fine :) thx !!